# Separating array and element from a JSON string

Tags: c#, .net, json, google-places-api

I am connecting you `Google Places API` to retrive results in the form of a `JSON` string. You can view the complete format of the string [Here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchPaging).

If you a look at it you will see that the actual results array starts after two elements which are `html_attributions` and `next_page_token`.

So When i try to deserialize it in this way:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var arr= serializer.Deserialize(result,typeof(string[]));
```

I get an empty array.

My question is how is there a way i can separate `html_attributions` and `next_page_token` fields and the pass the valid `results` array from the string to be deserialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the part where you wish to seperate the html_attributions and the next_page_token.

Wouldn't it be sufficient to just deserialize the response with whatever properties that you need?

For example, you can deserialize the response to only retrieve the values that you desire;

```
    // I represent the wrapper result
    class Result
    {
        public List<string> html_attributions { get; set; }

        public string next_page_token { get; set; }

        public List<ResultItem> results { get; set; }
    }

    // I represent a result item
    class ResultItem
    {
        public string id { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    // the actual deserialization
    Result Deserialize(string json)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(Result));
    }
```

Edit:
The reason that your deserialization doesn't return you a array of strings is because the response that you retrieve is infact an object and not an array, however the parameter within that object which is named results is an array. In order for you to deserialize more properties you'll have to define them in your "ResultItem" class, sorry for my poor naming here.

For instance, if you'd wish to also retrieve the icon property per result you'll have to add a property named "icon" of type string.

Meanwhile the property "photos" is an array, in order to deserialize it you'll have to create another class and add a property of type list/array of that newly created class, and it has to be named "photos" unless you use a different serializer or use DataContract and DataMember attributes (using the Name property for field mapping).

```
    // the representation of a photo within a result item
    class Photo
    {
        public int height { get; set; }

        public List<string> html_attributions { get; set; }

        public string photo_reference { get; set; }

        public int width { get; set; }
    }

    // I represent a result item
    class ResultItem
    {
        public string id { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }

        // the added icon
        public string icon { get; set; }

        // the added photos collection, could also be an array
        public List<Photo> photos { get; set; }
    }
```

Just look at the JSON result to figure out what other properties that you might want to add, for instance the "scope" property is an string whilst the "price_level" is an integer.

If I understand your comment correctly you're only interested in the actual results, you'll still have to deserialize the response correctly with its wrapper.

```
    // the actual deserialization
    List<ResultItem> Deserialize(string json)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var result = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(Result));

        return result.results;
    }
```

Edit2:
If you really want a string[] as a result you could simply take use of System.Linq using the code above.

```
string[] stringArray = result.results.Select(r => string.Format("id:{0} - name:{1}", r.id, r.name)).ToArray();
```

Edit3:
Instead of using the JavascriptSerializer you could use JObject functionality which can be found in the [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq](http://james.newtonking.com/json) library.

```
    var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);

    string[] results = jsonObject.SelectTokens("results").Select(r => r.ToString()).ToArray();
```

This will give you an array of strings where each value within the array is the actual json string for each result.

If you however would like to query for the coordinates only:

```
    var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);

    var coordinates = jsonObject["results"]
            .Select(x => x.SelectToken("geometry").SelectToken("location"))
            .Select(x => string.Format("{0},{1}", (string)x.SelectToken("lat"), (string)x.SelectToken("lng")))
            .ToArray();
```

This would give you an array of coordinates, eg:

```
[
    "-33.867217,151.195939",
    "-33.866786,151.195633",
    ...
]
```

Whatever approach you choose you'll be able to accomplish same results using either [Newtonsoft](http://james.newtonking.com/json) or the .net serializer, whilst the Newtonsoft approach would allow you to query without creating strong types for deserialization.

Comment: This is perfect almost what i need, just one last thing, now I have an object that contains all this value but how can I convert this `object` into a `string[]` of `List`?

Comment: I want to do something like `string [] arr = result.results;` But I cant becuase i get `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<abc.Models.model>' to 'string[]'`

Comment: Edited once more, however I don't understand why you wish to deserialize the response if you only intend to work with it as string values. Perhaps you should take a look at Newtonsoft or any other library that allows you to query json objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the point of *"[...] pass the valid results array from the string to be deserialized"*.

Maybe you need to switch to [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) and do something like this:

```
// You simply deserialize the entire response to an ExpandoObject
// so you don't need a concrete type to deserialize the whole response...
dynamic responseEntity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(
                             googlePlacesJson, new ExpandoObjectConverter()
                         );

// Now you can access result array as an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`...
IEnumerable<dynamic> results = responseEntity.results;

foreach(dynamic result in results)
{
   // Do stuff for each result in the whole response...
}
```